# Req user is undefined even after serialize it

Tags: javascript, node.js

The problem is when I want pass object to view. I got a message user is undefined. The object is defined after if statement is Match and in serializeUser function. I do not know why I lose this object in route to lobby.
Here I post the route code.

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var User = require('../models/user');
var Facebook = require('../models/facebook');
var passport = require('passport')
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var FacebookStrategy = require('passport-facebook').Strategy;

router.get('/lobby', function(req, res){
    console.log("User req "+req.user);// here I got the message user undefined and I do not know why
    res.render('lobby',{ user:req.user});
   // res.render('lobby');
});

router.get('/logout',function(req, res){
    req.logout();
    req.flash('success_msg', 'You have been logged out');
    res.redirect('/');
});

function ensureAuthenticated(req, res, next){
    if(req.isAuthenticated()){
        return next();
    }else{
        res.redirect('/');
    }
}

router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local', {
    successRedirect : '/users/lobby',
    failureRedirect : '/',
    failureFlash : true
}));


//Passport strategy
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    console.log("serizlize "+user); //here I got object user and it is defined 
    done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    User.getUserById(id, function(err, user) {
        done(err, user);
    });
});

passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
    function(username, password, done) {
        User.getUserByUsername(username, function(err, user){
            if(err) throw err;
            if(!user){
                return done(null, false, {message: 'wrong data'});
            }
            User.comparePassword(password, user.password, function(err, isMatch){
                if(err) throw err;
                if(isMatch){
                    return done(null, user);
                }else{
                    return done(null, false,{message: 'wrong data'});
                }
            });
        });
    }));


module.exports = router;
```

[enter link description here](http://pastebin.com/TD6F8Ezr)

*******Edit*****
Problem solved. I just red that you have to initalize express session before passport session. That works for me.
In your server file (my is app.js)

```
//express session
app.use(session({
    secret: 'yoursecrethere',
    saveUninitialized: true,
    resave: false
}));

//Passport init
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
```

Comment: Try returning the full user object in your `serializeUser` function, e.g. `done(null, user);`

Comment: @JonathanNielsen still the same